# Latex, can't compile .bib file -- "Emergency stop"

Tags: errors

I can't compile even a very short .bib file:

```
@article{Adams1994,
   author = {Adams, R. and Bischof, L.},
   title = {Seeded Region Growing},
   journal = {Ieee Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence},
   volume = {16},
   number = {6},
   pages = {641-647},
   note = {Nr972
Times Cited:827
Cited References Count:16},
   abstract = {We present here a new algorithm for segmentation of intensity images which is robust, rapid, and free of tuning parameters. The method, however, requires the input of a number of seeds, either individual pixels or regions, which will control the formation of regions into which the image will be segmented.  In this correspondence, we present the algorithm, discuss briefly its properties, and suggest two ways in which it can be employed, namely, by using manual seed selection or by automated procedures.},
   keywords = {image segmentation
region growing
semiinteractive image processing
watershed
segmentation
algorithm},
   ISSN = {0162-8828},
   DOI = {Doi 10.1109/34.295913},
   url = {<Go to ISI>://WOS:A1994NR97200008},
   year = {1994},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
```

Here is the relevant error log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdftex 2014.1.9)  7 APR 2014 12:05
entering extended mode
**C:/Users/XX/Desktop/Thesis_April/biblio.bib
(C:/Users/XX/Desktop/Thesis_April/biblio.bib)
*
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...ers/XX/Desktop/Thesis_April/biblio.bib

End of file on the terminal!

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

No idea what the problem is :s. I'm using MikTeX for compilation.

Comment: You don't compile `.bib` files! You compile the source file (with LaTeX), then use bibtex to create the citations, and then recompile the source file with LaTeX. So if your file is called "thesis.tex", your commands are "pdflatex thesis", "bibtex thesis", "pdflatex thesis" -- the name of the `.bib` file has nothing to do with it, though it will be referred to in your `\bibliography{}` command in the source file.

Comment: Biber produces an own log output. It has the ending `.blg`, have you looked through it?

Comment: This one looks like 'I do not understand BibTeX at all'. That's really covered by a general LaTeX intro, but I'm duping to something I hope will be at least some help.